# Session variable not returing value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two webform one is JournaL Book.aspx and another is Journal Entry.aspx.
The webform JournaL Book.aspx consists one image button i.e imgbtnentry and textbox i.e txtjournalname.And webform Journal Entry.aspx consists label i.e lbljournalbookname. Here I am trying to display whatever text i input into textbox i.e txtjournalname in lbljournalbookname in another page i.e Journal Entry.aspx on button click and if i doesnot input anything in textbox the label text should be Untitled Journal.So the problem is that whatever i input in textbox that is displayed in label text but when i doesnot input anything label text doesnot any thing insted of Untitled Journal in label text.

Code Behind Button i.e imgbtnentry in Journal Book.aspx

```
    protected void imgbtnentry_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtjournalname.Text != null)
    {
        Session["JournalBookName"] = txtjournalname.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Journal Entry.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Session["JournalBookName"] ="Untitled Journal";
        Response.Redirect("Journal Entry.aspx");
    }

}
```

code in page load in Journal Entry.aspx

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {           
        lbljournalbookname.Text = Session["JournalBookName"].ToString();            
    }             

}
```

Comment: Set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TextBox.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text(v=vs.100).aspx) never returns null, so this is pointless:

```
if (txtjournalname.Text != null)
{
    // ....
}
```

because `TextBox.Text` returns an empty string even if you explicitly assign `null`.

So use this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtjournalname.Text))
{
    Session["JournalBookName"] = txtjournalname.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Journal Entry.aspx");
}
else
{
    Session["JournalBookName"] ="Untitled Journal";
    Response.Redirect("Journal Entry.aspx");
}
```

[Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs,92b4f85cd223169c,references)

By the way, that's not only  an ASP.NET thing, even all winforms controls have the same behaviour. [Source of `Control.Text`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,952c66876790b53a)

Comment: Thanks for the help worked